# Raw socket in Linux Kernel

Tags: sockets, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have an issue with this code:

```c
bool send_packet(uint8_t *frame, const uint32_t size)
{
    int len, ret;
    struct iphdr *ip;
    struct msghdr msg;
    struct kvec vec;

    ip = (struct iphdr*)(frame + ETH_HLEN); // Align ip header with buffer

    tgb_pr_debug("packet ip version : %d\n",ip->version);
    tgb_pr_debug("packet from %pI4 to %pI4\n",&ip->saddr, &ip->daddr);
    tgb_pr_debug("packet ip protocol : %d\n",ip->protocol);

    memset(&msg,0,sizeof(msg));

    len = size - ETH_HLEN;
    vec.iov_base = ip;
    vec.iov_len = len;

    ret = kernel_sendmsg(sock,&msg,&vec,1,len);
    if (ret < 0) {
        pr_err("sendmsg return code %d\n",ret);
        return false;
    }

    kfree(frame);

    return true;
}
```

With high rate it's freeze the computer. Is socket right way to send packet in Linux Kernel?

Answer (score 0):

With this implémention i have no issue, it's work perfectly, if someone know why i'm interested

```
struct sk_buff* skb, *trailer;
struct net_device *dev;        


dev = dev_get_by_name(&init_net,"enp0s5"); 
skb = alloc_skb(size+ETH_HLEN+2,GFP_ATOMIC);



memcpy(skb_put(skb, size), frame, size);
kfree(frame); //free buffer get from ipseclib


skb_reset_network_header(skb);
skb->dev = dev;
skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;

skb_cow_data(skb,1,&trailer);

dev_queue_xmit(skb);
```

Comment: It's confusing as an answer. You need to put more effort to it.